# Return bad request Erros in Web API with Json and AJAX

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, rest

I want to return the error list that is in my child class and they return ok using a rest client.

I am not sure how to display the errors on the front end of my website on the forms to create a new child. I have included my create methods, controller below, any help is much appreciated

```
 [HttpPost]// POST api/Child
    public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody]Child obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { // check valid state
                repository.Insert(obj);
                repository.Save();
                return Ok(obj);
            }
            else // not valid request
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }


    } // end POST Create


//MY SCRIPT FOR THE CREATE
       // Called with "createForm" onSubmit
        function CreateChild() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: rootURL,
                dataType: "json",
                data: formToJSONCreate(),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('Child Added Succesfully');
                    clearCreateForm();
                    displayList();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Child create error: ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);

                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: formToJSONCreate() wt is this

Comment: what are you trying to achieve. you can get the data in the jquery error callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using this to put the errors in an object then append to the object and display in the div

```
 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var errors = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).ModelState
                    var errorText = Object.keys(errors).map((key) => errors[key])
                    console.log(Object.keys(errorText))

                    $('#formErrors').append(errorText.join(' <br>'))

                }
```